# Generating Leads and lags for non-consecutive time periods in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

With a `SAS` dataset like

```
Ob     x    year   pid  grp 
1    3.88   2001    1    a
2    2.88   2002    1    a 
3    0.13   2004    1    a 
4    3.70   2005    1    a 
5    1.30   2007    1    a 
6    0.95   2001    2    b 
7    1.79   2002    2    b 
8    1.59   2004    2    b 
9    1.29   2005    2    b 
10   0.96   2007    2    b
```

I would like to get

```
Ob   x      year    pid grp grp   X_F1      XL1
1   3.88    2001    1   a    a   2.88        .
2   2.88    2002    1   a    a     .        3.88
3   0.13    2004    1   a    a    3.7        .
4   3.7     2005    1   a    a     .        0.13
5   1.3     2007    1   a    a     .         .
6   0.95    2001    2   b    b    1.79       .
7   1.79    2002    2   b    b     .        0.95
8   1.59    2004    2   b    b    1.29       .
9   1.29    2005    2   b    b     .        1.59
10  0.96    2007    2   b    b     .         .
```

where for observations with the same `pid` and each year `t`,

- `x_F1` is the value of `x` in year `t+1` and
- `x_L1` is the value of x in year `t-1`

In my data set, not all `pid`s have observations in successive years.

My attempt using the `expand proc`

```
proc expand data=have out=want method=none;
    by pid; id year;
    convert x = x_F1 / transformout=(lead 1);
    convert x = x_F2 / transformout=(lead 2);
    convert x = x_F3 / transformout=(lead 3);
    convert x = x_L1 / transformout=(lag 1);
    convert x = x_L2 / transformout=(lag 2);
    convert x = x_L3 / transformout=(lag 3);
run;
```

did not account for the fact that years are not consecutive.

Comment: Would it help if you expanded the have dataset before calling PROC EXPAND, to make it have a record for every pid-year (with missing value for x where appropriate)?

Comment: My dataset have more than  8 million observations, if I cannot figure a better way I will consider that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could stick with `proc expand` to insert the missing years into your data (utilising the `extrapolate` statement).  I've set the `from` value to `day` as this is a sequential integer check for days which will work with your data as YEAR is stored as an integer rather than a date.

Like the other answers, it requires 2 passes of the data, but I don't think there's an alternative to this.

```
data have;
input x year pid grp $;
datalines;
3.88   2001    1    a
2.88   2002    1    a 
0.13   2004    1    a 
3.70   2005    1    a 
1.30   2007    1    a 
0.95   2001    2    b 
1.79   2002    2    b 
1.59   2004    2    b 
1.29   2005    2    b 
0.96   2007    2    b 
;
run;

proc expand data = have out = have1
    method=none extrapolate
    from=day to=day;
by pid;
id year;
run;

proc expand data=have1 out=want method=none;
    by pid; id year;
    convert x = x_F1 / transformout=(lead 1);
    convert x = x_F2 / transformout=(lead 2);
    convert x = x_F3 / transformout=(lead 3);
    convert x = x_L1 / transformout=(lag 1);
    convert x = x_L2 / transformout=(lag 2);
    convert x = x_L3 / transformout=(lag 3);
run;
```

or this can be done in one go, subject to whether the value of x is important in the final dataset (see comment below).

```
proc expand data=have1 out=want1 method=none extrapolate from=day to=day;
    by pid; id year;
    convert x = x_F1 / transformout=(lead 1);
    convert x = x_F2 / transformout=(lead 2);
    convert x = x_F3 / transformout=(lead 3);
    convert x = x_L1 / transformout=(lag 1);
    convert x = x_L2 / transformout=(lag 2);
    convert x = x_L3 / transformout=(lag 3);
run;
```

Comment: Can the early steps be replaced by adding `to=day` to the last `proc expand`, or do the conversions get performed before the imputation of missing observations? I would test but don't have SAS/ETS.

Comment: @Keith It is working; should I be concerned about the warning messages?

Comment: To answer @SRSwift, I didn't try it as I thought it wouldn't work.  Having run it, you do indeed get the same answers for x_F1 - x_L3, however there is a difference in the x value.  With the 2 step method, it sets the x value to missing when it inserts the missing years, however with the 1 step method it sets it to the value of the following year!  Assuming the x value is not necessary for the result, then a 1 step method works.  Of course, SAS may still be doing a 2 pass read of the data behind the scenes!  I'll update my answer

Comment: @Duna, no the warning messages are nothing to worry about here, although they are an unwelcome addition to the log!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach using `proc sql`. It joins the data with itself twice; once for the forward and once for the backward lag, then takes the required values where they exist.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select
        a.*,
        b.x as x_f1,
        c.x as x_l1
    from have as a
    left join have as b
        on a.pid = b.pid and a.year = b.year - 1
    left join have as c
        on a.pid = c.pid and a.year = c.year + 1
    order by 
        a.pid, 
        a.year;
run;
```

Caveats:

- It will not expand too well with larger numbers of lags.
- This is probably not the quickest approach.
- It requires that there be only one observation for each `pid` `year` pair, and would need modifying if this is not the case.

Comment: `Ob` is line number in `SAS` how can I reference that in the code

Comment: The data is already sorted by `pid year` and there is only one observation for each `pid year` pair. I am a newbie for `SAS`

Comment: `proc sql` can change the order of observations during its processing, so you cannot rely upon it to maintain the input order. It cannot reference the input ordering in a simple manner. However, you can achieve the same result by using `order by a.pid, a.year` as this will request that the output data be orders by those two variables. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort your data per group and per year.
2. compute x_F1 in a data step with a lag and a condition like this: `if (year and lag(year) are consecutive) then x_F1=lag(x)`
3. Sort your date the other way around
4. Compute x_L1 similarly.

I'm trying to write you a working code right now.
If you provide me with a data sample (a data step with an infile e.g.), I can better try and test it.

This seems to work with my data:

```
/*1*/
proc sort data=WORK.QUERY_FOR_EPILABO_CLEAN_NODUP out=test1(where=(year<>1996)) nodupkey;
    by grp year;
run;

quit;

/*2*/
data test2;
    *retain x;
    set test1;
    by grp;
    x_L1=lag(x);
    if first.grp then
        x_L1=.;
    yeardif=dif(year);
    if (yeardif ne 1) then
        x_L1=.;
run;

/*3*/
proc sort data=test2(drop=yeardif) out=test3;
    by grp descending year;
run;

quit;

/*4*/
data test4;
    *retain x;
    set test3;
    by grp;
    x_F1=lag(x);
    if first.grp then
        x_F1=.;
    yeardif=dif(year);
    if (yeardif ne -1) then
        x_F1=.;
run;
```

Comment: In step2 `yeardif` is not being performed within the group `grp`. I added `if first.grp then yeardif=. ;` after defining `yeardif`. It seems to be working. Is that correct?

Comment: I dont see how this ads value. because if `first.grp` then `x_L1=.` already. adding this will make `yeardif=.` wich will make `(yeardif ne 1)` true thus `x_L1=.` once more.